# How to make the instance inside Django form take multiple values?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm making a Django blog and I want to make the user edit his post. I have 2 forms to render, Post Form that includes (title, post image, content, category) and another separated form for the post tags that includes (tag name). To edit the tags I have to get all the tags related to the post and set them to the `instance` attribute which takes only one object (and I have multiple tags for one post).
Here are my Models:

```
class PostTags(models.Model):
    tag_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tag_name

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    picture = models.ImageField(null=True,upload_to='images/')
    content = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User,blank=True,related_name='likes')
    dislikes = models.ManyToManyField(User,blank=True,related_name='dislikes')
    date_of_publish = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True,blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(PostTags,blank=True)
      
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Here are my Forms:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title','picture','content','category']
        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'picture': forms.FileInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'content':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'category' : forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        }

class TagsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PostTags
        fields = ['tag_name']
        widgets = {
            'tag_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'data-role': 'tagsinput'})
        }
```

and here is my try to get all tags in the tags form in views.py

```
def editPost(request,post_id):
    post = Post.objects.get(id= post_id)
    post_form = PostForm(instance=post)
    # tagInstance = []
    for tag in post.tag.all():
        print(tag)
        newTag = PostTags.objects.get(tag_name=tag)
        tag_form = TagsForm(instance=newTag)
        # tagInstance.append(newTag)
 
    # print(tagInstance)
    
    
    # if request.method == 'POST':
    #     form = PostForm(request.POST,instance=post)
    #     if form.is_valid():
    #         form.save()
    #         return redirect('post')
    context = {"post_form":post_form,'tag_form':tag_form}
    return render (request,"dj_admin/editpost.html",context)
```

The above try resulted in only the last tag rendered to the tags form which is expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably a cleaner solution but this should work:

```
def editPost(request,post_id):
    post = Post.objects.get(id= post_id)
    post_form = PostForm(instance=post)
    context = {}
    context['post_form'] = post_form
    count = 0
    for tag in post.tag.all():
        print(tag)
        newTag = PostTags.objects.get(tag_name=tag)
        tag_form = TagsForm(instance=newTag)
        count += 1
        context['tag_form'+str(count)] = TagsForm(instance=newTag)
    context['tag_form_counter'] = count
    return render (request,"dj_admin/editpost.html",context)
```

So, in your template you must to check the tag_form_counter variable to know how many tag_forms you have. And make a forloop to show them.

Comment: This showed input fields for tags with the number of the counter which is not the best solution as you said but it worked for now, thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to render all tag_forms related to the post inside your template.

You can achieve what you want using [django model inline_formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.models.BaseInlineFormSet)

forms.py:

```
from django.forms import inlineformset_factory
from .models import Post, PostTags

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title','picture','content','category']
        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'picture': forms.FileInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'content':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'category' : forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        }

class TagsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PostTags
        fields = ['tag_name']
        widgets = {
            'tag_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'data-role': 'tagsinput'})
        }

TagFormSet = inlineformset_factory(PostTags, Post, fields=('tag_name',))
```

views.py:

```
from .forms import PostForm, TagsForm, TagFormSet

def editPost(request,post_id):
    post = Post.objects.get(id= post_id)
    post_form = PostForm(instance=post)
    tag_formset = TagFormSet(instance=post)     
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST, instance=post)
        tag_formset = TagFormSet(request.POST, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid() and tag_formset.is_valid():
            form.save()
            tag_formset.save()
            return redirect('post')
    context = {'post_form': post_form, 'tag_formset': tag_formset}
    return render (request, 'dj_admin/editpost.html', context)
```

and then inside your template file you can simply add `{{ tag_formset }}` like this:

```
<form method="post">
    {{ formset }}
</form>
```

Comment: This raised an error "ValueError: 'dj_blog.Post' has no ForeignKey to 'dj_blog.PostTags'."
I don't know if that is related to using ManyToManyField instead of ForiegnKey in the Post Model but the relation type here is many to many. so what do you think?